# Adobe AIR, Android app won't go upside-down unless aspectRatio is set to portrait

Tags: android, air, orientation

My -app.xml file is a simple,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/4.0">
    <id>com.sixminute.plaintester</id>
    <filename>OtherTester</filename>
    <name>OtherTester</name>
    <versionNumber>0.0.0</versionNumber>

    <initialWindow>
        <content>[This value will be overwritten by Flash Builder in the output app.xml]</content>
        <!-- 
            <aspectRatio>portrait</aspectRatio>
         -->
        <renderMode>direct</renderMode>
        <autoOrients>true</autoOrients>
        <fullScreen>true</fullScreen>
        <visible>true</visible>
    </initialWindow>

    <android>
        <manifestAdditions><![CDATA[
            <manifest android:installLocation="auto">
                <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
                <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
            </manifest>
        ]]></manifestAdditions>
    </android>
    <iPhone>
        <InfoAdditions><![CDATA[
        ]]></InfoAdditions>
        <requestedDisplayResolution>high</requestedDisplayResolution>
    </iPhone>
</application>
```

And the entry point file, is just

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.StageAlign;
    import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
    import flash.text.TextField;

    public class OtherTester extends Sprite
    {
        public function OtherTester()
        {
            super();

            stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
            stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;

            var tx:TextField = new TextField();
            tx.text = 'hello world';
            tx.x = tx.y = 10;
            addChild(tx);

            trace(stage.supportedOrientations.join(', '));
        }
    }
}
```

the trace statement prints the full,

default, rotatedLeft, rotatedRight, upsideDown

But no matter how I turn, I only get default (upright portrait), rotatedLeft and rotatedRight, never upsideDown.

I'm using AIR 4.0, and have tested it on a Nexus 5, Samsung S2 and S3, and an iPhone 4.  All works as expected on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

If I manually handle it with,

```
stage.addEventListener(StageOrientationEvent.ORIENTATION_CHANGE, onReorientation);

...

protected function onReorientation(event:StageOrientationEvent):void
{
    if(event.afterOrientation != stage.orientation)
    {
        stage.setOrientation(event.afterOrientation);
    }
}
```

everything works as expected.  When you go upside down, event.afterOrientation is upside down, but stage.orientation is still whatever it was before.  Obviously this is a bug, no?